# Displaying a subset of features in a facet of a multi-layer plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, facet

I'm trying to generate a multi-layered plot where the points in one layer gets displayed only in a fraction of the facets created using data from another layer. In the code below, the points in red are either `x1` or `x2` (just like the row labels of the facet).

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1000)

#generate first df
df1 = data.frame(x=rep(rep(seq(2,8,2),4),4), 
                 y=rep(rep(seq(2,8,2),each=4),4),
                 v1=rep(c("x1","x2"),each=32),
                 v2=rep(rep(c("t1","t2"),each=16),2),
                 v3=rbinom(64,1,0.5)) 

# generate second df
df2 = data.frame(x=runif(20)*10,
                 y=runif(20)*10,
                 v4=sample(c("x1","x2"),20,T))

# create theme
t1=theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), text = element_text(size=18),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), strip.background= element_blank(),
         axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())

# plot
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, colour = factor(v3)), shape=15,  size=5) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(NA,"black")) + facet_grid(v1~v2) +
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=x,y=y, shape=v4), colour="red", size=4) + 
  coord_equal(ratio=1) + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 10) + t1
```

[image]

**EDIT**: The black squares are generated by manually setting the colour of `df1$v3 = 1` to `black` and `df1$v3 = 0` to `NA`. **/EDIT**

But what I actually want is to display only those points from `df2` with `df2$v4 = x1` in the first row of facets, and `df2$v4 = x2` in the second row of facets (corresponding to the values of `df1$v1` and the row labels of the facet). 
[image]
[image]

I've done this by generating two separate graphs...

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df1[df1$v1=="x1",], shape=15,  size=5, 
  aes(x=x, y=y, colour = factor(v3)), ) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(NA,"black")) + facet_grid(~v2) +
  geom_point(data=df2[df2$v4=="x1",], aes(x=x,y=y), colour="red", size=4) + 
  coord_equal(ratio=1) + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 10) + t1

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df1[df1$v1=="x2",], shape=15,  size=5, 
  aes(x=x, y=y, colour = factor(v3)), ) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(NA,"black")) + facet_grid(~v2) +
  geom_point(data=df2[df2$v4=="x2",], aes(x=x,y=y), colour="red", size=4) + 
  coord_equal(ratio=1) + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 10) + t1
```

... but I'm curious if a single plot can be generated because with my actual data set I have several `x's` and it is time consuming to piece the graphs together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does it help if we just rename `df2$v4` or make a new column called `df2$v1`, for faceting purposes:

```
df2 <- dplyr::rename(df2, v1 = v4)
df2$v1 <- df2$v4
# either works
```

then `ggplot` will distribute the data points as you would like, with this:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, colour = factor(v3)), shape=15,  size=5) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = c(NA,"black")) +
    facet_grid(v1~v2) +
    geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=x,y=y), colour="red", size=4) + 
    coord_equal(ratio=1) + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 10) + 
    t1
```

[image]

not 100% sure I grasp your problem...

Comment: Yes, you have understood my problem. The goal was to display points from df2 that only correspond to the values used to subset and create facets. I'm embarrassed I did not try this ridiculously easy step! Thank you.